# How to stop a gif from re-starting on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on creating slots in react but for the first time I press the button, if the first "slot" is updated, the gifs seem to re-start on the other ones.
Most people seem to have the opposite problems of not being able to restart/stop gifs, but I haven't found any similar issues.

- When the second "slot" is updated the third gif does not re-start
- When I re-start all slots with a button, the gifs do not re-start when updating the first again

My state keeps the images of the slots, which is either a gif of the slot spinning or a picture of the result. At first I had 1 list in the state, but assumed all slots would re-render when 1 element of the list updated, so I split it up into 3 different variables.

I thought maybe I could solve the problem by making sure the image (semantic-ui-react) element does not re-render so I even tried extracting the element into a separate component so the prop doesn't change, but that also didn't work.

I also tried adding a fourth slot in the state that gets updated first because the problem only seemed to appear after updating the "first" slot. The gifs didn't re-start on updating the 1st slot (the new one, without element), but then the others re-started on updating the 2nd and sometimes even 3rd (inconsistent).

In the code I put the 3 setState methods in a list to loop over them, I also tried doing it separately, also didn't work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import Button from '../UI/Button';
import Center from '../UI/Center';

const Slots = () => {
  const [image1, setImage1] = useState('./image1');
  const [image2, setImage2] = useState('./image2');
  const [image3, setImage3] = useState('./image3');

  const allImage = [...];

  const spin = () => {
    const spins = getSpins();
    const win = spins[0] === spins[1] && spins[0] === spins[2];

    const setImagesFns = [setImage1, setImage2, setImage3];
    setImagesFns.forEach((setImageFn) => { setImageFn('./spinning.gif'); });
    
    let counter = 0;
    const spinning = setInterval(() => {
      setImagesFns[counter](allImages[spins[counter]]);
      counter++;
      if (counter === 3) clearInterval(spinning);
    }, 1800);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Center>
        <Image src={image1} />
        <Image src={image2} />
        <Image src={image3} />
      </Center>

      <Button callback={spin} text='Spin' />
    </>
  );
}

export default Slots;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what the issue is. Does "spinning.gif" for 2nd entry resets its animation when you update 1st one from "spinning.gif" to "image1.gif"?

Comment: Yes, the first one gets update to an image, not a gif. But yes, then the 2nd and 3rd entry reset their animation.